# Missing JSON-format docs

Tags: swagger-ui, api-platform.com

I'm setting up a simple API to give access to our legacy backend to a new frontend; I'm using API Platform 2.7 as we are not running PHP 8 yet.
The HTML Swagger UI works fine, showing all the resources and their operations, but when accessing the JSON version for clients (api/index.json), it only list the names of the two resources, without operations or schemas:

```
{
  "resourceNameCollection": [
    "App\\Entity\\Client",
    "App\\Entity\\Plant"
  ]
}
```

There is a similar result when using JSONLD (api/index.jsonld):

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Entrypoint",
  "@id": "/api",
  "@type": "Entrypoint",
  "client": "/api/clients",
  "plant": "/api/plants"
}
```

I don't think I have changed anything that could cause this, and so far I haven't found anything on the docs about it.